# Journal - DispatchQueue - self.tableView.reloadData() not being called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm just starting out and have put together another List application because there aren't enough out there... but I'm running into an issue where the reloadData() isn't being called after entering a new entry for the journal. If I recompile the app again in XCode, the new entry then appears on the tableView.

I've included the signal 1 SIGTERM error that appears when the app is being recompiled.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBAction func addNewItem(_ sender: Any) {
        return
    }

    @IBOutlet var entityTableView: UITableView!


    var items: [Entity] = [] //Should be same name as new Entity in the dataModel
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


    //Calls the getData which will fetch the new entry and then reload the view
    //The register will linkt he UITableViewCell class with the tableView
    //estimatedRowHeight and rowHeight define the label size and I intentionally want text cut off (journal entries might be quite long) so a preview works
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    //Will reload the table every time that the view is shown to allow it to show the most recent entries
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        getData()
        print ("\(items)")
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "entry")
    }

    //Func will get the data. Print to check that data has been pulled and then refreshes the
    func getData() {
        do {
            items = try context.fetch(Entity.fetchRequest())
            print (items)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print("Unable to fetch the data")
        }
    }
}

extension TableViewController {

    //Will have the items presented as most recent on the top
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = items.reversed()[indexPath.row].newEntry

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let DeleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, view, success) in
            print("Delete")
        })
        DeleteAction.backgroundColor = .red

        let item = self.items [indexPath.row]
        self.context.delete(item)
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

        self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [DeleteAction])
    }
}
```

And the viewController for the addNewEntry is:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class addNewEntryViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var journalEntryField: UITextView!

    @IBAction func cancelEntry (_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var headerForNewEntry: UILabel!

    @IBAction func saveNewEntry(_ sender: Any) {
       guard let enteredText = journalEntryField?.text else {
                 return
             }

             if enteredText.isEmpty ||  journalEntryField?.text == "Type anything..."{

             let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Type Something", message: "Your entry was left blank.", preferredStyle: .alert)
             alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default) { action in

             })

             self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

         } else {

                 guard let entryText = journalEntryField?.text else {
                     return
                 }

                 let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
                 let newEntry =  Entity(context: context)
                newEntry.newEntry = entryText

                 (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

                 dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    //Will have the delegate set to the current view
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        journalEntryField.delegate = self
    }

    //Func will hide the keyboard after pressing the Return button
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if (text == "\n") {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

> `[<Journal__Core_Data_.Entity: 0x600003423e80> (entity: Entity;
>   id: 0xcae729498383650b
>   <x-coredata://71565814-E7F1-4D16-852F-7D8CBEA199F2/Entity/p1>; data:
>   <fault>), <Journal__Core_Data_.Entity: 0x600003427de0> (entity:
>   Entity; id: 0xcae72949838f650b
>   <x-coredata://71565814-E7F1-4D16-852F-7D8CBEA199F2/Entity/p2>; data:
>   <fault>)] [<Journal__Core_Data_.Entity: 0x600003423e80> (entity:
>   Entity; id: 0xcae729498383650b
>   <x-coredata://71565814-E7F1-4D16-852F-7D8CBEA199F2/Entity/p1>; data:
>   <fault>), <Journal__Core_Data_.Entity: 0x600003427de0> (entity:
>   Entity; id: 0xcae72949838f650b
>   <x-coredata://71565814-E7F1-4D16-852F-7D8CBEA199F2/Entity/p2>; data:
>   <fault>)] 2019-12-18 14:56:25.896548+0800 Journal (Core
>   Data)[12470:652660] [Warning] Warning once only: Detected a case where
>   constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a table view
>   cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and
>   using standard height instead. Cell:
>   <Journal__Core_Data_.TableViewCell: 0x7fb367f6d8c0; baseClass =
>   UITableViewCell; frame = (0 28; 414 99); text = 'Poop face';
>   clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer:
>   0x600001769b00>>`

Answer (score 0):

In your 'TableViewController' file
replace `var items: [Entity] = []`

with this

```
var items: [Entity] = []{
        didSet{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

this will reload your tableView on every new entry.After this you don't need to add `tableView.reloadData()` anywhere down in the Controller.

Comment: Just added that and still facing the same issue I'm afraid. Now I'm getting an error message at the line 'NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "entry")' with the error _Result of 'NSFetchRequest<ResultType>' initializer is unused_